# Erro: Nome duplicado para procedimento ou função

Tags: portugol

Eu estou treinando o uso de procedimentos no VisualG e queria saber porque o código abaixo apresenta o erro:

> "Nome duplicado para procedimento ou função: 'SEXO'".

Relembrando, o objetivo principal não é otimizar o código, e sim saber o motivo do erro. Só coloquei um único procedimento 'Sexo', porém o VisualG insiste que o nome está duplicado.

```
algoritmo "Seletor de Selecionados"
// Função :  Selecionar selecionados, óbvio
// Autor :  Rodrigo Matos Aguiar
// Data : 16/10/2016
// Seção de Declarações 
var
   Sex, Rep: Caractere // Sex - Sexo, CorC - Cor do Cabelo, Rep - Repetir
   Id, ContM, ContF, CorC, HS, MS: Inteiro // Id - Idade, ContM - Contador Masculino, ContF - Contador Feminino
   // CorC - Cor do Cabelo, HS - Homens Selecionados, MS - Mulheres Selecionadas
Procedimento Final(A, B: Inteiro)
inicio
      EscrevaL("---------------")
      EscrevaL("Resultado Final")
      EscrevaL("---------------")
      EscrevaL("Total de homens com mais de 18 anos e cabelo castanho: ", HS)
      EscrevaL("Total de mulheres com idade entre 25 e 30 anos e cabelo louro: ", MS)
FimProcedimento
Procedimento Cabelo
inicio
      EscrevaL("Qual a cor de cabelo?")
      EscrevaL("---------------------")
      EscrevaL("[1] Preto            ")
      EscrevaL("[2] Castanho         ")
      EscrevaL("[3] Louro            ")
      EscrevaL("[4] Ruivo            ")
FimProcedimento
Procedimento Sexo (var A, B: Inteiro)
var C: Caractere
inicio
      EscrevaL("Qual o sexo? [M][F] ")
      Leia(C)
      Escolha C
              Caso "M"
                   A <- 1
              Caso "F"
                   B <- 1
      FimEscolha
FimProcedimento
inicio
// Seção de Comandos
Repita
   EscrevaL("-----------------------")
   EscrevaL("Seletor de Selecionados")
   EscrevaL("-----------------------")
   Procedimento Sexo (ContM, ContF)
   EscrevaL("Qual a idade? ")
   Leia(Id)
   Se (Id > 18) entao
      ContM <- ContM + 1
   FimSe
   Se (Id > 25) e (Id < 30) entao
      ContF <- ContF + 1
   FimSe
   Procedimento Cabelo
   Leia(CorC)
   Escolha CorC
          Caso 2
               ContM <- ContM + 1
          Caso 3
               ContF <- ContF + 1
   FimEscolha
   Se (ContM = 3) entao
      HS <- HS + 1
   FimSe
   Se (ContF = 3) entao
      MS <- MS + 1
   FimSe
   EscrevaL("Quer continuar? [S][N] ")
   Leia(Rep)
Ate (Rep = "N")
    Procedimento Final(HS, MS)
    fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está declarando os procedimentos novamente quando vc usa a palavra  "Procedimento", em outras palavras, quando o compilador lê a palavra procedimento ele entende que vc está declarando um novo procedimento e nesse caso é o mesmo nome..

Sempre que vc quiser utilizar a função basta chamar o nome dela, exemplo:

```
Sexo (ContM, ContF)
```

Ao invés de

```
 Procedimento Sexo (ContM, ContF)
```

Em seu código existem vários outros lugares como Cabelo e Final no qual vc está colocando a palavra "Procedimento" na frente, eles também possivelmente apresentarão erro.

Antes de perguntar no SO você deveria pesquisar pelo menos como se realiza uma chamada de função nesta sua pseudo-linguagem (primeiro link do google por "visualg procedimento"):
http://www.eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem4.htm

**Declaração:**

```
Procedimento Sexo (var A, B: Inteiro)
var C: Caractere
inicio
      EscrevaL("Qual o sexo? [M][F] ")
      Leia(C)
      Escolha C
              Caso "M"
                   A <- 1
              Caso "F"
                   B <- 1
      FimEscolha
FimProcedimento
```

**Utilização:**

```
..
..
Sexo (ContM, ContF)
..
..
```

Comment: Eu já fiz dois algoritmos com Procedimento e em nenhum deles deu erro, porque eu tinha feito correto. Desculpe pela minha falta de atenção!

Comment: Sem problemas, o começo é dificil mas logo vc pega o jeito. Nao desista =D Depois aprenda a linguagem C ou Java, voce nao vai se arrepender